# YouTube APIs - How do we generate one Token to access all YouTube channels (Brand Accounts)

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

My understanding, we need to have unique token for each channels(Brand Accounts) in order to upload a video from one account to others account using YouTube APIs.

Is there any other way to use single token to access all the YouTube channels(Brand Accounts) ?

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube api is channel based.  When a user logs in they must pick a channel and consent to the access to that channel.   There is no way to make a generic token that works against all a users channels.

Your going to have to login once for each channel and store a token for each one.

> "onBehalfOfContentOwner" and "onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel"

Are features used only by YouTube partner accounts. to use them you must have be using a CMS account. Only the top YouTube accounts are invited to have YouTube Partner status.

Comment: thanks for replying.

I'm wondering what use of "onBehalfOfContentOwner" and "onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel" optional parameter in youtube API?